# Parameters in Crystal Reports from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters, crystal-reports

My report don´t accept the parameter.

I have created a parameter with "City" name.
In my code i want to full it:

```
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
crystalReport.SetParameterValue("City", lblCiudad.Text);
viewer.ReportSource = crystalReport;
```

the problem is that the report doesnt filter with my parameter, show without it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with formula:

```
crystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula = "{Clientes.Nombre} = '" + nombreCliente + "' AND {Registros.Host} = '" + host + "' AND  {Registros.Servicio} = '" + service + "' AND {Registros.Fecha} <= " + "DateTime(" + fF.Year.ToString() + "," + fF.Month.ToString() + "," + fF.Day.ToString() + ","+fF.Hour.ToString() + "," + fF.Minute.ToString()+","+fF.Second.ToString()+") AND {Registros.Fecha} >= " + " DateTime(" + fI.Year.ToString() + "," + fI.Month.ToString() + "," + fI.Day.ToString() + ","+fI.Hour.ToString() + "," + fI.Minute.ToString()+","+fI.Second.ToString()+")";
```